# How to add custom visualization for pointer types in VS2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, natvis

I am trying to write a [custom visualizer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/09/28/debug-visualizers-in-visual-c-2015/) for pointers of a C++ class, say Element, by creating a .natvis file in VS2015.

```
class Element
{
   int id;
   ......
};

int main()
{
   Element* pElem = GetElement();  // Visualise this pointer!

}
```

I want the debugger to show me value of the member `id` of the element when I hover my mouse over the *pointer* variable. How can I do this? So far I have tried the following, but it does not seem to be working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <!-- VC 2015 -->

  <Type Name="Element*">
    <DisplayString>{ id={*this.id} }</DisplayString>
  </Type>

</AutoVisualizer>
```

Comment: Why not `this->id` or `(*this).id`? The operator precedence of member access is higher than indirection. I am not sure it works with natvis.

Comment: Maybe `{ id={*this.id} }` should be `{{id={*id} }}`. Also how do you install final file?

Comment: @S.M. I think `this->id` would require extra escaping for `>`. And `this` is not required since expressions are evaluated in the context of object.

Comment: @VTT : To install the natvis script, I have placed the file under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers" . These are auto-loaded on start-up. You can have project specific visualizers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add the `*`. And there is no need for `*this.` when accessing a member of the current context (also see the comments regarding precedence of operators).

```
<Type Name="Element">
  <DisplayString>{ id={id} }</DisplayString>
</Type>
```